# Complex Sorting a List of Objects Efficiently

Tags: python, performance, sorting, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm trying to make sorting of objects in my program as fast as possible. I know that sorting with a cmp function is deprecated in python 3.x and that using keys is faster, but I'm not sure how to get the same functionality without using a cmp function.

Here's the definition of the class:

```
class Topic:
    def __init__(self, x, y, val):
        self.id = val
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

I have a dictionary full of `Topic` to float key, value pairs and a list of Topics to be sorted. Each topic in the list of `Topic`s to be sorted has an entry in this dictionary. I need to sort the list of topics by the value in the dictionary. If two topics have a difference in value <= .001, the topic with higher ID should come first.

Here's the current code I'm using:

```
topicToDistance = {}
# ...
# topicToDistance populated
# ...
topics = topicToDistance.keys()
def firstGreaterCmp(a, b):
  if abs(topicToDistance[a]-topicToDistance[b]) <= .001:
    if a.id < b.id:
      return 1
  if topicToDistance[a] > topicToDistance[b]:
      return 1
  return -1
# sorting by key may be faster than using a cmp function
topics.sort(cmp = firstGreaterCmp)
```

Any help making this as fast as possible would be appreciated.

Comment: For optimisation, head to codereview.stackexchange.com- this question belongs there.

Comment: Okay I wasn't sure if it was okay to post here considering code review is in beta.

Comment: I disagree, this is not just an optimization question.  It's a question about how to do the sort using one strategy (key function) instead of another (cmp function), and there's a legit reason to want to do that (because cmp is no longer supported in Python 3).

Comment: That said, did you look at [`functools.cmp_to_key`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key)?  It won't make things any faster, but it will work in Python 3.

Comment: No I hadn't seen that. Thanks, I was curious about how to do this in Python 3.

Comment: `topicToId = {"A": 3, "B": 2, "C": 1}`

`topicToDistance = {"A": 0.0000, "B": 0.0005, "C": 0.0011}`

`A < C  # d(A, C) = 0.0011 > 0.001 and 0.0000 < 0.0011`

`A > B  # d(A, B) = 0.0005 < 0.001 and 3 > 2`

`B > C  # d(B, C) = 0.0006 < 0.001 and 2 > 1`

`A > C  # transitivity: A > B > C`